# .less CSS watch feature only works locally?

Tags: local, watch, less

According to http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/ I should be able to set up a "watch" feature for less.

I mainly work directly on remote servers. Either through opening up file directly through FTP or using a server found through a network.

Will this still work? Or do the files have to be local to be "watched"?

I'm using Windows if that makes a difference.

Many thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The watch feature is something that happens on your own local development computer. You could run it on your server, but it would have to run constantly in the background, so it's probably not the best option. The watch options is not a feature of less.js, but instead of other LESS CSS compliers. A compile operation is usually a one-time operation, i.e. you call the compiler, it compiles and returns you to the shell prompt. With the `-w` or `--watch` switch, your LESS compiler will watch your specified .less file(s) and convert them as soon as they change.

This watching features is a design-time live compiler option, whereas with less.js your less files are converted at run-time. Another alternative is a compile-time operation where you invoke a less compiler as part of a build step (like with Ant).

**Ruby**
If you do `gem install less` with Ruby installed, you get the old command-line Ruby compiler. It isn't kept up by Cloudhead anymore, so it's mostly unsupported and doesn't get any new features, etc. When you run it, you can call `lessc input.less output.css -w`. Without the `-w` switch at the end, LESSC will compile it one time and return you to your prompt. With the `-w` switch, it will continue to watch the file for changes and recompile it each time you edit the file.

**.NET**
If you have [DotLessCSS](http://dotlesscss.org), (you're probably on windows) you can type `dotless.Compiler input.less output.css --watch` which does the same thing.

**PHP**
If you are using [LESSPHP](http://leafo.net/lessphp/), you can also call that from the command line with `plessc -w input.less output.css`, again, the `-w` will do the same thing.

**Mac**
If you are on a mac, you can use [LESS.Air](http://incident57.com/less/). Specify which files you want the app to look at, tell it you want it to keep watching those files, and it will compile in the background without the command line.

**Air**
On Windows, Mac or Linux, you can use [this less parser](http://www.proving-ground.be/less/) which is a clone of LESS.Air. It works the same way, but is cross-compatible and uses less.js under the hood.

Comment: OK thanks for answering this so fully. - I thought that might be the case

Comment: Then feel free to mark it as the answer, and upvote it if you like.

Comment: Got it! - tried to mark it up but I don't have enough credits. thanks again for taking the time.